# cannot find - No such file or directory - libusb - Ubuntu 32 & 64 bit

Tags: files, compiling, directory, 32-bit, debug

I'm trying to write a program that transfers data to my device.
I'm using libusb. 
I had many problems to install its package in both 32 & 64 bit edition of Ubuntu 16 LTS.
Commands for installation:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dbg
```

also tried: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/libusb.html

"dpkg -l libusb*" in Ubuntu 64 bit; shows that it has been installed while 32 bit one announces "no such package...".

Compiling command:

```
sudo gcc -g -o usbtest usbtest.c -lusb-1.0
```

In Ubuntu 64 bit it compiled while in 32 bit one, following note appeared:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb-1.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but I was sure that it exist then I tried following command and it compiled without any error.

```
sudo gcc -g -o usbtest usbtest.c -L/usr/local/lib -lusb-1.0
```

at the end when I execute my program, it can not find my device in other words can not open the device.
following presents debugging procedure in Ubuntu (32 & 64 bit):

```
141      int r = 1; 
(gdb) s
143      r = libusb_init(NULL); 
(gdb) 
libusb_init (context=0x0) at ../../libusb/core.c:1983
1983    ../../libusb/core.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
1985    in ../../libusb/core.c
(gdb) 
__GI_getenv (name=0xb7fb2f16 "LIBUSB_DEBUG") at getenv.c:34
34  getenv.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../memcmp.S:80
80  ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../memcmp.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
__GI_getenv (name=0xb7fb2f16 "LIBUSB_DEBUG") at getenv.c:35
35  getenv.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
__strlen_ia32 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S:43
43  ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
44  in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S
```

I don't have any idea what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve; do you need libusb to work on both 32 and 64 bit? Or only one of them?
In any case, the library must be installed specifically for the right architecture. The install command by default would only install its "own" version of the library.
You can specifically tell it to install both versions:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev:i386
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev:amd64
```

for 32 and 64 bit, respectively.
You could also check directly for the library files, on my system (16.04) they live in

```
32bit: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
64bit: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

(if you're in doubt, `dpkg-query -L libusb-1.0-0-dev` shows where they are installed.)

As for the libusb you compiled yourself, you need to keep track that you are using the correct version when linking your program. Maybe you are mixing 32 and 64 bit versions in /usr/local/lib ? gcc / ld wouldn't know to keep them apart then.

As for the debug session, gdb ist just trying to show you source lines but doesn't know where to find the library's source files. Otherwise I can't see anything that's obviously going wrong here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have both 32 & 64 bit Ubuntu separately in Virtual Machine. I just tried to execute my codes in both. I also added :i1386 and :amd64 to my code, and checked those directories. I do not have any idea why my system acts like that an also why my code, isn't able to open my device.